# python merge lists using join()

Tags: python

I have got the following list:

```
lst = [['a','!b'], ['91','q'], ['!t','3','p']]
```

I want the following as output:

```
test = a and !b or 91 and q or !t and 3 and p
```

The individual literals in the sublist is made into a single literal and joined using 'and' and then the sublists are joined together using 'or'

I tried the following, can someone correct my code?

```
   def output(self):
      temp = ['and'.join(sublist[i]) for i in sublist]
      test = ['or'.join(sublist) for sublist in self.lst]
      return self.test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All at once:

```
def output(lst):
    return " or ".join(" and ".join(s) for s in lst)
```